# Merging Dataframes in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've 2 Dataframes, say A & B. I would like to join them on a key column & create another Dataframe. When the keys match in A & B, I need to get the row from B, not from A.

For example:

DataFrame A:

```
Employee1, salary100
Employee2, salary50
Employee3, salary200
```

DataFrame B

```
Employee1, salary150
Employee2, salary100
Employee4, salary300
```

The resulting DataFrame should be:

DataFrame C:

```
Employee1, salary150
Employee2, salary100
Employee3, salary200
Employee4, salary300
```

How can I do this in Spark & Scala?

Comment: You have added the Spark SQL tag. If you understand SQL, this should be a simple `JOIN` operation

Comment: I am not good at SQL. Can u please share this simple JOIN operation? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dfA.registerTempTable("dfA")
dfB.registerTempTable("dfB")

sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT coalesce(dfA.employee, dfB.employee), 
       coalesce(dfB.salary, dfA.salary) FROM dfA FULL OUTER JOIN dfB
ON dfA.employee = dfB.employee""")
```

or

```
sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT coalesce(dfA.employee, dfB.employee),
  CASE dfB.employee IS NOT NULL THEN dfB.salary
  CASE dfB.employee IS NOT NULL THEN dfA.salary
  END FROM dfA FULL OUTER JOIN dfB
ON dfA.employee = dfB.employee""")
```

Comment: As per my understanding of 'right outer join', it won't select 'Employee3' in this case, right?

Comment: What I like about this is that I can dynamically build the 'sql'. Do I need to add 'alias' such as, coalesce(dfB.salary, dfA.salary).alias("salary")? In any case, I will try this & if it works will give you an up vote. Thanks.

Comment: @DilTeam The alias is only necessary in the dataframes API if you later needed to reference the resultant table. This is purely a SQL solution.

Comment: Actually, isn't there a bug in this logic? Let's say 'salary' value was changed from 100 to NULL. So in dfA it's 100 & dfB it's NULL. The resulting value would be 100 - which is not correct. It was changed to NULL. Am I missing something?

Comment: Here's how I believe we can fix this:  IF(ISNULL(dfB.employee), dfA.salary, dfB.salary)  instead of 'coalesce'. Correct?

Comment: CASE dfB.employee IS NOT NULL THEN dfA.salary  shouldn't this IS NULL? In any case, we prefer 'IF(ISNULL'... It's more compact when we have over 100 columns. Personal preference - unless someone proves to me that the 'CASE' is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming dfA and dfB have 2 columns emp and sal. You can use the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}

val dfB1 = dfB
  .withColumnRenamed("sal", "salB")
  .withColumnRenamed("emp", "empB")

val joined = dfA
  .join(dfB1, 'emp === 'empB, "outer")
  .select(
    f.coalesce('empB, 'emp).as("emp"),
    f.coalesce('salB, 'sal).as("sal")
  )
```

NB: you should have only one row per Dataframe for a giving value of emp

Comment: This is a good answer. But I need to build 'sql' dynamically so I think LostInOverflow's answer will work better. If you disagree, let me know, but thanks for answering.

Comment: @DilTeam you can build Scala DSL dynamically just as you can build SQL. Often, it is simpler to work with the DSL because OO principles make reuse much easier. Also, note that you can use `functions.expr(anySqlExpression)` to create `Column` objects from the text  of SQL expressions.

Comment: @Marl The code had a bug: `coalesce` takes `Column*`, not column names. I fixed it.

Comment: I am a bit confused on how to generate f.coalesce('empB, 'emp).as("emp"), f.coalesce('salB, 'sal).as("sal")  dynamically. Feeling dumb :( Any pointers?